# Showing line number of source code in Electron app devtools

Tags: typescript, electron, capacitor, source-maps

I want to show the source code line number in my Electron/Capacitor app instead of the chunk line number in the console section of the dev tools.

[Current display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3v8UD.png)

Is there any way to do this?

I enabled inLineSources and inLineSourceMap and I added the sourceRoot in the tsconfig.json of the project but that didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.